# Using Apache Commons CLI on Debian

Tags: java, debian, apache-commons-cli

On a Debian system, I installed Commons CLI with `apt-get install commons-cli-java`, but now I can't figure out how to compile a program with it. I've tried every permutation of setting $CLASSPATH I could think of, but nothing worked. So what is the next step after getting the library installed?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out, needed to add `/usr/share/java/commons-cli.jar` to $CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know offhand, but

```
dpkg -L commons-cli-java
```

Will show you all the files that the package owns, which should give you a better idea of where you need to look.

the `-doc` is probably work a look as well.